# Celery and RabbitMQ not starting

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I installed RabbitMQ, Celery, Flask and Python but when I tried to run celery worker to test. It does not work, these are the error that was pop out in the cmd.

```
[2019-01-18 09:56:37,443: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ansonkho\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 317, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "c:\users\ansonkho\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "c:\users\ansonkho\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 40, in start
    self.sync(c)
  File "c:\users\ansonkho\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 44, in sync
    replies = self.send_hello(c)
  File "c:\users\ansonkho\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 57, in send_hello
    replies = inspect.hello(c.hostname, our_revoked._data) or {}
```

below is my code:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('test_celery', broker='amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost/myvhost',backend='rpc://')
```

Comment: If my solution solves your problem please accept it as the best answer. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[2019-01-18 09:56:37,443: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
```

As mentioned in the error, there is no broker running. You need to start `Rabbitmq` before making a connection to it. That is why the consumer is throwing `Connection to broker lost` as the broker is not running.